# HTML string construction found, please use DOM element construction instead

Tags: javascript, jquery

El VIP Scanner de wordpress me da este error en JS, alguien sabe sobre esto?

```js
$( '.canned_response .button-box').append('<a href="#" id="set-send" data-status="' + status + '" class="backend-button">Set Status to "' + status + '" and Send</a>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Te está diciendo que uses un objeto HTML, no un texto.
Crea un elemento "a" con un `document.createElement("a")`, indícale los parámetros, e introdúcelo en el `append` en vez del texto "`<a href...`".
Algo parecido a esto:

```js
var elemento = document.createElement("a");
elemento.href="#";
elemento.id="set-send";
elemento.data-status=status;
elemento.class="backend-button";
elemento.innerHTML="Set Status to " + status + " and Send";
$( '.canned_response .button-box').append(elemento);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, y en caso de esta linea como se aplicaria?

( '.edit-php .subsubsub .all a').html( 'Not Achived (' + ( $live_count - achive_count ) + ')' );

Comment: No entiendo a que se refiere esa linea.

Comment: Es el mismo error pero tambien se aplica en esta linea digamos

Comment: Si da el mismo error, la idea es la misma...pero en vez del append, en html, en este caso debes crear un elemento texto con un createTextNode, creo.